# how can i uncheck DevExpress Gridview 's checkbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gridview, devexpress

how can i uncheck DevExpress Gridview 's checkbox ?  i have a gridview with checkboxes. i need to uncheck all gridview Checkbox. How can i do that?

Comment: Which GridView are you using?  ASPxGridView or XtraGrid or may be DXGrid for WPF?  If you are using ASPxGridView, do you mean checkBoxes in the command column?

Comment: i solved it. i am using aspxGridview: Gv.Selection.UnselectAll() enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list of object with a bool property to bind to the checkbox column.

Column definition : 
this.gvCheck.ColumnEdit = this.repositoryItemCheckEdit1;
            this.gvCheck.FieldName = "**EstaSeleccionada**";
            this.gvCheck.Name = "gvCheck";
            this.gvCheck.Visible = true;
            this.gvCheck.VisibleIndex = 0;
            this.gvCheck.Width = 51;

Property use: 
seniales.ForEach(s => s.**EstaSeleccionada** = true/false);
gcSeniales.DataSource = new List();
gcSeniales.DataSource = seniales;
gcSeniales.Update();